# Simulate error "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Tags: c#, exception, microsoft-dynamics

I'm running a long process which updates some opportunities 1 by 1 in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4. Occasionally this will stop midway through with the error: *"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."* As it's intermittent it's something I think happens due to network blips but not certain. In all circumstances if I restart the process (which kicks off where it left off) it starts again straight away.

I've written the following code to try and cope with this scenario as I want this to be an overnight process (1 off):

```
int Retries = 0;
bool Ready = false;
while (!Ready && Retries < 5)
{
    try
    {
        using (CrmService service = GetCrmServiceInstance())
        {
            service.Update(opp);
            Ready = true; //break out of the while loop as connection is working.
        }
    }
    catch (SoapException se)
    {
        Retries++;
        if (Retries > 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occurred updating opportunity " + opp.opportunityid.Value + ". Error: " + se.Detail.InnerXml);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Retries++;
        if (Retries > 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occurred updating opportunity " + opp.opportunityid.Value + ". Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My theory is that if it initially gets this error that it will retry to do the update and hopefully work again. If the number of retries exceeds 4 then throw an error.

I now want to test this code to see if it adequately works for my purposes. I've tried running the long process (6 hours) to see if I get the error, with break points on the SoapException and Exception blocks to be able to step through if it breaks on doing an update but it didn't. So, is there a way to simulate this error so I can test my new code?

Comment: Restart the CRM app pool? Pull the network cable?

Comment: @stuartd - My app is running on a virtual machine, so presumably pulling the network cable isn't an option. I also don't have access to the server that crm sits on to restart the app pool. However, I'll see if I can get someone to do it.

Comment: @stuartd - just got a dba to restart the CRM app pool as you suggested and that seemed to do what I needed. If you put that as an answer I'm happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to simulate a connection failure would be to restart the CRM application pool, which is CrmAppPool by default.